# Firebase Auth (javascript): 'TypeError: user.delete is not a function' when linking accounts

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link an anonymous firebase account with a provider account, and I'm using the following javascript code which I've copied from the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

This is the exact code I'm using:

```
function mergeAccounts(credential){

    console.log("merging guest account with provider account");

    var auth = firebase.auth();

    // Get reference to the currently signed-in user
    var prevUser = auth.currentUser;
    // Sign in user with another account
    auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
      console.log("Sign In Success", user);
      var currentUser = user;
      // Merge prevUser and currentUser data stored in Firebase.
      // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application

      // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
      return user.delete().then(function() {
        // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
        return prevUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
      }).then(function() {
        // Sign in with the newly linked credential
        return auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Sign In Error", error);
    });
}
```

When I am logged into firebase as an anonymous user, and then attempt to log in using my google account, the above code succeeds in logging me with google (the line `console.log("Sign In Success", user);` works as expected and shows me the user details in the console.  But I then get an error which says `Sign In Error TypeError: user.delete is not a function at 16login.js:212`which refers to the line which has `return user.delete().then(function() {`

The documentation and the code snippet I used seem to suggest that `delete()` is a function of `user`, so I'm a bit stumped as to why it's throwing this error.

Any help much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential) method, not `signInWithCredential`, so the return value is a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) object. You need to access the `user` through the `user` property of the returned property of your callback function :

```
    auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(userCredential) {
          const user = userCredential.user; // HERE
          console.log("Sign In Success", user);
          var currentUser = user;
          // Merge prevUser and currentUser data stored in Firebase.
          // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application

          // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
          return user.delete().then(function() {
            // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
            return prevUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
          }).then(function() {
            // Sign in with the newly linked credential
            return auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Sign In Error", error);
        });
```

Comment: It says not to use this section to say 'thanks', but I'm not sure where else to say it, so - thanks - it works!  Much appreciated.